# To replace elements from one list when it match's elements with other list

Tags: python, list, replace, list-comprehension, element

I have 2 lists in python.

I have to replace elements from 1st list with '-1' when the elements of the list match's elements from 2nd list
example -

```
a = [1,5,8,9,9,3,88,85,1,4,8,81,4,1,6,9,7,10]
c = [3, 4, 5, 8, 9, 81, 85, 88]
```

output should be

```
'[1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,1,4,-1,-1,4,1,6,-1,7,10]'
```

I have tried-

```
a = [1,5,8,9,9,3,88,85,1,4,8,81,4,1,6,9,7,10]
c = [3, 4, 5, 8, 9, 81, 85, 88]
for t in c :
     list = ["-1" if x == c[t] else x for x in a]
print(list)
```

Comment: You have to provide Your efforts on this matter

Comment: also for text formatting to code use ```

Comment: Please go through the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) and [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)  to see how this site works and to help you improve your current and future questions, which can help you get better answers.
"Show me how to solve this coding problem?" is off-topic for Stack Overflow.
You have to make an honest attempt at the solution, and then ask a *specific* question about your implementation.
Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing tutorials and documentation.

Comment: The logic of your request is unclear.  `a` has 18 elements to start, but 17 when you finish.  You talk about matching the `b` list, but you have 4 remaining in `a` even though that element appears in `b`.

Answer (score 3):

Give this a try.

```
a = [1,5,8,9,9,3,88,85,1,4,8,81,4,1,6,9,7,10]
b = [3, 4, 5, 8, 9, 81, 85, 88]
for index, x in enumerate(a):
    if x in b:
        a[index] = -1
print(a)
```

You can shorten it to your likings but it gets the job done.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution, which I find easier to understand

```
a = [1, 5, 8, 9, 9, 3, 88, 85, 1, 4, 8, 81, 4, 1, 6, 9, 7, 10]
b = [3, 4, 5, 8, 9, 81, 85, 88]

for item in a:
    if item in b:
        a[a.index(item)] = -1

print(a)
```

Comment: By using `list.index()` you are doing twice the amount of work as the current top answer. "Easier to understand" is a valid reason to post an answer, I just thought I'd give you some feedback.

Comment: The top answer is faster, but I felt like for beginners (including me), this would be much simpler, and would be a go-to solution. I belive that it's much better to use code that you understand rather than something faster when learning